# Control performance of Branch and Bound algorithm

Tags: matlab

I wrote a script (at the bottom) to solve the travelling salesman problem (TSP) with the branch and bound algorithm. My script allows two input possiblities.

1) Coordinates of the cities in an excel file with the file name 'Test'. A city can be described also by more than two dimensions. Later the script generates the distance matrix.

2) Insert direct the distance matrix in the script.

At the moment the second input variant is active for my code. (15 cities, A-O)

I have no programming experience and therefore my code looks maybe a little bit inelegant. Nevertheless I would like to measure the performance of the algorithm. What are the best ways to achieve that? Is it possible to establish a performance graph? Additionally I would like to visualize the results. Is it possible to generate a map with the city connections or even a branch and bound tree?

I hope someone could help me

Best

```
clear all
clc

% Choose between two input possibilities: Coordinates in Excel file
% 'Test'from different cities or insert distance matrix direct here in script

% %%%Input coordinates of the cities via Excel file
% data = xlsread('Test.xlsx',1)
% dist = dist(data(:,2:5)') % how many coordinates are necessary to describe the location from one city
% dist(dist==0) = inf

%%%Input directly distance matrix
% Input information
A = [inf, 4, 12, 7, 4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 6, 7, 12, 3, 5, 20];
B = [5, inf, 20, 18, 6, 3, 4, 8, 9, 23, 1, 12, 5, 4, 9];
C = [11, 5, inf, 6, 1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 12, 31, 5, 1, 14, 5];
D = [10, 2, 3, inf, 5, 7, 8, 8, 6, 21, 4, 7, 5, 5, 1];
E = [1, 2, 6, 9, inf, 9, 10, 8, 45, 12, 11, 5, 6, 2, 11];
F = [17, 7, 6, 5, 11, inf, 12, 8, 63, 1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 8];
G = [11, 8, 3, 9, 3, 5, inf, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 12, 4, 8];
H = [12, 14, 2, 5, 4, 8, 4, inf, 12, 4, 1, 23, 7, 4, 56];
I = [4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 6, 7, 12, 3, inf, 7, 5, 6, 12, 14];
J = [6, 1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 12, 31, 5, 1, inf, 12, 1, 2, 6];
K = [7, 8, 8, 6, 21, 4, 7, 5, 5, 1, 11, inf, 13, 1, 2];
L = [1, 6, 1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 12, 8, 9, 10, 12, inf, 7, 5];
M = [8, 4, 6, 7, 12, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7, 12, 3, inf, 14, 15];
N = [21, 4, 7, 5, 5, 1, 21, 4, 7, 5, 5, 1,13, inf, 1];
O = [4, 12, 7, 4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 6, 7, 12, 3, 5, 20, inf];
% Generate distance matrix
dist = [A; B; C; D; E; F; G; H; I; J; K; L; M; N; O]

% Initalization
MaxCity = length(dist);
i = 1;
n = 1;
Parentcity = 1;
Childcity = 0;

% Array
costarray = zeros(MaxCity, 2);
wayarray = zeros(MaxCity, 2);
wayarray(1,:)=[1 0]

% Reduktion und Kosten der ParentCity
row_reduction = min(dist, [], 2);
row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;
M_row_reduced = dist - row_reduction;

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);
M_working = M_row_reduced - column_reduction;
M_working(isnan(M_working)) = inf;
M_reduced = M_working;
costparent = sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction);

for n = [n:1:MaxCity]              % levels der baumstruktur

for i = [i:1:MaxCity]; % childcity i= childcity
    if i == Parentcity ||i==1
        cost = inf;

    else
        M_working= M_reduced;
        M_working(Parentcity, :) = inf;
        M_working(:, i) = inf;
        M_working(i, Parentcity) = inf;
        M_working(Parentcity,i) = 0; %!!!!

        row_reduction = min(M_working, [], 2);
        row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;      
        M_row_reduced = M_working - row_reduction;    

        column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);
        M_working = M_row_reduced - column_reduction; 
        M_working(isnan(M_working)) = inf;            


        cost = costparent+ sum(row_reduction) + sum(column_reduction)+ M_reduced(Parentcity, i);
    end
    costarray(i, :) = [i,cost];
end
i = 1;

% minimum der cost array finden
[M, I] = min(costarray);
childcity = I(1, 2);
costparent = M(1, 2);
wayarray(n +1, :) = [childcity, dist(wayarray(n,1),childcity)]; %änderung!!

% nimm childcity, reduziere matrix für diese
M_working=M_reduced;
M_working(Parentcity, childcity) = inf;
M_working(:, childcity) = inf;
M_working(childcity, Parentcity) = inf;
M_working(Parentcity,childcity) = 0; %!!!!

row_reduction = min(M_working, [], 2);
row_reduction(isinf(row_reduction)) = 0;      
M_row_reduced = M_working - row_reduction;    

column_reduction = min(M_row_reduced);
M_working = M_row_reduced - column_reduction; 
M_working(isnan(M_working)) = inf;            

M_reduced=M_working;

Parentcity = childcity;
end
wayarray(n+1,2)=dist(wayarray(n,1),1)
gesamtlaenge=sum(wayarray(:,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, this might not be an appropriate question for SO because it calls for opinions. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also, please add a tag to help us see what language this is (I'm guessing matlab.)

Comment: Remove the `branch` tag as this has nothing to do with code source code control branches.  (Hover your mouse over a tag to see what it means.)